# created() hook twice on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

on page refresh the created hook happen to be called twice for some weird reasons but that doesn't happen if I come from another route.

```
created() {         
    this.$store.dispatch('setInternalComponents',true);
    this.getCurrencies();              
},
```

you can find my router configuration below:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Auth },
  { path: "/resetpassword", component: Resetpwd },
  { path: "/forgotpassword", component: Forgotpwd },
  { path: "/firstlogin", component: FirstLogin},
  { 
    path: "/dashboard", 
    component: Dashboard,
    beforeEnter(to,from,next){
        if (store.state.accessToken)
        {
          next()
        }else
          next('/')
    }
  },
  { path: "*", redirect: "/" }
];

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
  mode: "history"
});
```

Comment: you need to provide more code. Is their a watcher? how are your routes setup? what is your router configuration? is something causing your page to reload once loaded possibly?

Comment: I've added the routes configuration above.

Comment: I found the problem. it happened because I was dispatching an action to the store within the created method so I moved it in the beforeEnter event in route configuration instead.

Comment: post it an an answer your question for others, also feel free to upvote my comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the issue myself.
If we update the Vuex store on created/mounted hooks it will re-render the component so I moved the logic on the beforeEnter event in the routes configuration to avoid that behaviour.

code changed below:

```
{ 
    path: "/dashboard", 
    component: Dashboard,
    beforeEnter(to,from,next){
        if (store.state.accessToken)
        {
          store.dispatch('setInternalComponents',true);
          next()
        }else
          next('/')
    }
  },
```